# Which will be the java regex to parse the following log file

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a log file in java. The log files contains information about a Time Processing and events. The lines that I'm interested in and also the information within are marked in bold within the log line entry example. For the following one I need to extract, the **Processing Time** and **eventID(200)**:

> 15:04:53 Camera 192.168.1.112 -> Frame 2: **Processing Time 13.000000ms** 
>   15:04:53 -> Frame 2 : Camera 192.168.1.111: newImage(T) errorID(0) **eventID(200)** noOfBoundingBox(0),bbinfo(),noCentroid(0) , centroidInfo(0,0,0%;/), imageReturned(F)
>
> 16:04:53 Camera 192.168.1.111 -> Frame 2: **Processing Time
>   14.000000ms**  16:04:53 -> Frame 2 : Camera 192.168.1.111: newImage(T) errorID(0) **eventID(201)** noOfBoundingBox(0),bbinfo(),noCentroid(0)
>   , centroidInfo(0,0,0%;/), imageReturned(F)

I am having a problem to create the regex pattern and how do i can get the processing time and event id for the specific IP in the log file?

Comment: What did you try and what did it output?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract it by following code.

```
public static void stackOverFlowRegex(){
        String text = "15:04:53 Camera 192.168.1.112 -> Frame 2: Processing Time 13.000000ms 15:04:53 -> Frame 2 : Camera 192.168.1.111: newImage(T) errorID(0) eventID(200) noOfBoundingBox(0),bbinfo(),noCentroid(0) , centroidInfo(0,0,0%;/), imageReturned(F) 16:04:53 Camera 192.168.1.111 -> Frame 2: Processing Time 14.000000ms 16:04:53 -> Frame 2 : Camera 192.168.1.111: newImage(T) errorID(0) eventID(201) noOfBoundingBox(0),bbinfo(),noCentroid(0) , centroidInfo(0,0,0%;/), imageReturned(F)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(Processing Time(.*?)ms)(.*?)(eventID\\((.*?)\\))");//(Processing Time(.*?)ms)+(eventID\\((.*?)\\))
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.format("%s => %s\n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(4));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. this is the output I need ^^

Comment: @lighthing actually people accepts the answer if it is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RegEx {

    public static String testdata = "15:04:53 Camera 192.168.1.112 -> Frame 2: Processing Time 13.000000ms 15:04:53 -> Frame 2 : Camera 192.168.1.111: newImage(T) errorID(0) eventID(200) noOfBoundingBox(0),bbinfo(),noCentroid(0) , centroidInfo(0,0,0%;/), imageReturned(F)";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(testdata);
        String processingTime = testdata.replaceFirst(".*Processing Time ", "");
        processingTime = processingTime.replaceFirst(" .*", "");
        System.out.println(processingTime);
        String eventId = testdata.replaceFirst(".*eventID\\(", "");
        eventId = eventId.replaceFirst("\\).*", "");
        System.out.println(eventId);        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! it's help me a lot ^^